# top how to monitor processes using regex name?

Tags: top

I monitor several processes with i.e. '#top -p 22055,21995' But there are many of them all starting with fwk* i.e. fwk3_dev, fwk5_dev

```
  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                        
22055 admin      0 -20  832m 302m  41m S   20  2.5  14973:53 fwk3_dev                                                                                       
21995 admin      0 -20  834m 304m  41m S   14  2.6  10179:55 fwk5_dev
```

How I can monitor using regex name of process fwk* I mean all processes with starting from 'fwk'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`top`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html) will not do this by itself, but you could write a simple shell script which runs `top` in batch mode (the `-b` option), filtering *that* using grep, and in a loop.  It would not be interactive.

For example

```
while :; do clear; top -b -n 1 |grep ' fwk' ;sleep 1; done
```

[`grep`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html) does recognize regular expressions, given the `-E` option.  But your example can be handled with just a leading blank and "fwk" (unless you happen to have a user with the same name).

Some versions of [`top`](http://www.unixtop.org/man.shtml) may need a different option (such as `-d`) to run just once in batch mode.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
# first generate a comma-separated list of matching PIDs
pids=$(ps a -o pid,args | awk '/[f]wk/ {print $1}' | xargs | sed -e 's/ /,/g')
# then run top with that list
top -p $pids
```

NOTE: if any `fwk*` processes are started in the short time between generating the list and running `top`, they will not be included in the display.